# Bind a DataGridComboBoxColumn to an Enum

Tags: wpf, data-binding, wpfdatagrid

I have a simple DataGrid which I want the user to add some rows to.
However I want one of the columns to be a ComboBox with it's values taken from an **enum**.

What's the simplest way of doing this in my XAML?

I've tried following but I get the error *"Two-way binding requires Path or XPath"*

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="myEnumData"
                MethodName="GetValues" 
                ObjectType="{x:Type sys:Enum}">
        <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
            <x:Type TypeName="local:MyEnum" />
        </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
    </ObjectDataProvider>
</Window.Resources>
```

...

```
   <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="MyHeader" DisplayMemberPath="EnumValue" 
            SelectedItemBinding="{Binding Source={StaticResource myEnumData}}">
        </DataGridComboBoxColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are trying to bind the selected item when you (presumably) want to bind the list of available items.  Change your binding to this:

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="MyHeader"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource myEnumData}, Mode=OneWay}">
</DataGridComboBoxColumn>
```

Comment: Hi Steve, I don't get the error now - thanks. However the ComboBox is empty. I should mention that the DataGrid is empty to begin with and I am filling in all the rows (there is no existing data).

Comment: Do you mean that the `ComboBox` does not have a selected item, or that there are no items in the drop down when you click on it?

Comment: I mean there are no items in the ComboBox

Comment: Ah, I just spotted the `DisplayMemberPath` - that's probably causing the values not to be displayed.  I've updated my example

Comment: Steve, OK almost there. The enum is in the ComboBox when I click on it. However the ComboBox is not visible when I click off it (i.e. move to the next column etc.)

Comment: Do you see anything in the cell if you select one of the values from the `ComboBox`?

Comment: I'm not certain, but that may just be the behaviour of the data grid combo box... Sorry I can't help on that part!

Comment: Steve, I got it. Just need to add SelectedValueBinding="{Binding Path=.....}" Cheers

Answer (score 10):

XAML

```
xmlns:ext="clr-namespace:Project.Core.Tools;assembly=Project.Core"

<DataGridComboBoxColumn ItemsSource="{x:Static ext:Extensions.GetEnumTypes}" SelectedItemBinding="{Binding EnumType}" />
```

Static Class

```
public static IEnumerable<EnumType> GetEnumTypes => Enum.GetValues(typeof(EnumType)).Cast<EnumType>();
```

Answer (score 0):

XAML:

`<DataGridComboBoxColumn ItemsSource="{Binding Orientantion, Mode=OneTime, Converter={Converts:EnumToItemSourceConverter}}"  SelectedItem="{Binding Orientantion}"/>`

C#:

```cs
public enum OrientantionTypes : int { Custom, Automatic}

public OrientantionType Orientantion { get; set;}
```

Converter:

```cs
public class EnumToItemSourceConverter: MarkupExtension, IValueConverter
{
    public override object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (!(value is Enum ))
            return null;
        {
            Type enumType = value.GetType();
            var listType = typeof(List<>);
            var constructedListType = listType.MakeGenericType(enumType);

            var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(constructedListType);

            foreach (var m in Enum.GetValues(enumType))
            {
                ((IList)instance).Add(m);
            }
            return (IList)instance;
        }

        return null;
    }

    public virtual object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        return this;
    }
}
```